# Como iniciar um projeto Django usando virtualenv?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, python-2.7, framework

Já procurei e achei diversas maneiras e convenções diferentes para a criação de um projeto em Django utilizando ambiente virtual (virtualenv). Existe algum padrão para isso? Alguém me ajuda com um passo a passo correto?

Uso python 2.7 + Django 1.8

Comment: Um padrão para o que exatamente? Aliás, está perdendo a nova versão 3.5 do Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que você já tenha o pip instalado, para utilizar a abordagem de ambientes isolados é muito simples, ainda mais com o virtualenvwrapper. O virtualenvwrapper é, como o nome já indica, um wrapper para o virtualenv, trazendo comandos que facilitam o uso das suas funções.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Se você não tiver instalado o virtualenv antes, o comando acima fará isso para você.

Após isso, para criar um novo ambiente fica muito simples:

```
mkvirtualenv nome_da_env
```

Ao finalizar, sua env vai estar criada, e se você tiver realizado de maneira correta a [configuração do virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file) (pro caso de usar um SO Unix-like), sua env já vai estar ativada. Para desativar bastar executar o comando:

```
deactivate
```

E para ativar, ou trocar de ambiente:

```
workon nome_da_env
```

Em resumo: instale o virtalenvwrapper, configure-o como citado no link mais acima, e use os estes comandos para facilitar sua vida.

Answer (score 0):

Costumo utilizar o [generator-django](https://github.com/diegotoral/generator-django) para Yeoman.

Para instala-lo utilize o comando abaixo:

```
npm install -g generator-django
```

Crie o `virtualenv` e o ative:

```
virtualenv myproject --no-site-packages
source myproject/bin/activate
```

Agora crie o diretório do projeto e execute o gerador do Yeoman:

```
mkdir myproject && cd myproject
yo django
```

Mais detalhes para sua instalação na [documentação do projeto](https://github.com/diegotoral/generator-django#getting-started).

Comment: Como o Yeoman é feito em Node.js recomendo a instalação do [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Isso vai facilitar as coisas :D

Answer (score 0):

> Já procurei e achei diversas maneiras e convenções diferentes para a
>   criação de um projeto em Django utilizando ambiente virtual
>   (virtualenv).

Criar um projeto em Django não tem relação com o virtualenv, não sei se a pergunta foi mal formulada, mas criar o projeto depende apenas em ter o Django, não tendo dependência com o ambiente. O Virtualenv é apenas uma ferramenta para criar ambientes isolados.

Sendo assim, bastando ter o Django instalado na máquina ou no ambiente do virtualenv, você pode criar o seu projeto usando `django-admin startproject meuprojeto`, esse é o padrão, instalar qualquer outro pacote para fazer isso é redundante.

Talvez a sua pergunta seja:

## Como criar um ambiente isolado e como iniciar o ambiente?

No MacOSX eu faço da seguinte maneira:

```
iMac:~ Orion$: pip install virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper
```

No arquivo **.profile** adiciono as referências responsáveis por executar o virtualenvwrapper (armazenando no arquivo você tem certeza que ao reiniciar o computador serão recarregadas as variáveis):

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Para criar um ambiente (ao criar ele já ativa o ambiente):

```
iMac:~ Orion$: mkvirtualenv ambiente_teste
```

Para desativar:

```
(ambiente_teste)iMac:~ Orion$: deactivate
```

Para reativar (usando `workon`):

```
iMac:~ Orion$: workon ambiente_teste
```

E **para criar um projeto** (verifique se está criando o projeto no diretório desejado):

```
(ambiente_teste)iMac:~ Orion$: django-admin startproject meuprojeto
```